# iTerm2 - Export Snippets

Tags: iterm2

How do I export Snippets in iTerm2?

I'm looking to backup my Snippets so that my other teammates can use them too.

- Exporting my profile, but Snippets isn't in the json
- Preferences > Shortcuts > Snippets (the two buttons that appear to be export/import), but that doesn't seem to work.
- I also looked in my preferences directory (Mac), but I'm not seeing them.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac,

- Go to iTerm » Settings » Shortcuts » Snippets
- Select any one Snippet
- Then Select All by pressing `Cmd+A`
- There is an icon with Arrow pointing Up
- Save at preferred location with preferred name
- extension of saved file will be `<file-name>.it2snippets`

Same file can be imported back to new machine.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Just for info, the file is actually a Json file.